# How do I password protect an MVC route with IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to password protect one of the routes of my MVC 5 app. I don't want to go through the process of Forms Auth or [Authorize] attributes etc. I just want to deploy the app as usual and use IIS to protect one of the routes.

e.g. `mydomain.com/`   is open to the world

`mydomain.com/Folder1`   pwd protected

Using IIS to pwd protect a physical folder is quick and easy, but if I create a virtual directory or application to match that mvc route, I get a 403 forbidden because it thinks I'm trying to list the directory contents and there obviously isn't a default file because the folder is virtual.

If a virtual directory/application is the way to go, where do I point it to?

Comment: IIS does not have any "password protect" feature like other web servers. You have to use a proper authentication method (like forms, or others).

Comment: You can absolutely add authentication on a website or folder with IIS. I've done it

Answer (score 0):

The following is not the solution I was looking for. I wanted a non-progammatic implementation that could be added/removed/modified without the need for any coding or deployment (i.e. in IIS).
The reason I decided to use it is because of how simple and quick it was to implement. It took way less time to implement than I spent looking for - and trying - IIS solutions.

Obviously, this is not suitable for security in most applications, but for its ease-of-implementation, it suited my scenario pretty well

It is Basic Authentication using a custom ActionFilter and an attribute on the controller.

First, create your ActionFilter:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string BasicRealm { get; set; }
    protected string Username { get; set; }
    protected string Password { get; set; }

    public BasicAuthenticationAttribute(string username, string password)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
    }

    public BasicAuthenticationAttribute()
    {
        this.Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        this.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        this.BasicRealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BasicRealm"];
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var auth = req.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
        {
            var cred = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            var user = new { Name = cred[0], Pass = cred[1] };
            if (user.Name == Username && user.Pass == Password) return;
        }
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", BasicRealm ?? ""));
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

Then, add the attribute to the controller you want to protect:

`[BasicAuthentication()]`

or this if you wanted to hardcode your username & pwd for some reason

`[BasicAuthentication("username", "password", BasicRealm = "your-realm")]`

And that's it. Just add the credentials to your web.config and create a custom 401 error page if you like.

I guess it's also easy enough to add another web.config key to act as a flag to activate to deactivate the authentication if you wanted to be able to turn it off without redeploying your application